# Add a link to a image

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

How do I add a link to the image? I am unsure what code to use.

```
<?php
    $company_image = '';
    $company_description = '';

    if (!empty($options['company_photo'])){
        $company_image = $options['company_photo'];
    }
    else {
        $company_image = 'https://nemo-uploads-clone.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/homeabout/image/1/philly.jpg';
    }
```

Comment: Hello, what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

> you can't straightly add a link to the image variable which is defined,
>    but you can add the link like this:

in html you can use this:

```
<a href="https://www.something.com">
  <img src="img.jpg">
</a>
```

in php, you can use "html tags" inside of ".php" file like this:

```
echo  '<a href="https:\\www.wikipedia.org"> <img src="img.jpg"/> </a>';
```

the code above, will show an image on the screen that refers to wikipedia link!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML for an image with a link

```
<a href="https://www.example.com">
  <img src="https://www.example.com/img.png">
</a>
```